# Can someone show the work with some details that $f^{-1}$ is not continuous at $(1,0)$?

Tags: general-topology

Show that the function $f: [0, 2 \pi) \to S^1$ defined by $f(t)=e^{it}=(\cos t, \sin t)$ is not homeomorphic.

**Answer:**

This function is bijective and continuous. But $f^{-1}$ is not continuous at $(1,0)$.

But how to show that $f^{-1}$ is not continuous at $(1,0)$.

From definition of continuous function, we call $f:X \to Y$ a continuous function if for $x \in X$ there are neighborhoods $U$ in $X$ and $V$ in $Y$ with $x \in U$ and $f(x) \in V$, then $f(U) \subset V$.

Following this definition,

We have $f^{-1}(1,0)=0 $.

Let $U$ be any open set containing $(1,0)$ and $V$ be any open set containing $0$, we have to show that $f^{-1}(U) \not\subset V$.

But I can not show it.

Can someone show the work with some details that $f^{-1}$ is not continuous at $(1,0)$ ?

There is a explanation in Wikipedia as below:

The function $f^{-1}$ is not continuous at the point $( 1 , 0 )$ because although $ f^{-1}$ maps $( 1 , 0 )$ to $0$,  any neighbourhood of this point also includes points that the function maps close to $2 \pi $, but the points it maps to numbers in between lie outside the neighborhood.

But I could not understand it clearly. How they choosing neighborhood?

Comment: Try thinking about limits (this is often more intuitive and perfectly alright when dealing with metric spaces). As $x\in S^1$ approaches $(1,0)$ "from below/clockwise", you will see that $f(x)$ approaches $2\pi \neq 0$.

Comment: @MartinR, I could understand the explanation given in Wikipedia as  follows: The function $f^{-1}$ is not continuous at the point $( 1 , 0 )$ because although $ f^{-1}$ maps $( 1 , 0 )$ to $0$,  any neighbourhood of this point also includes points that the function maps close to $2 \pi $, but the points it maps to numbers in between lie outside the neighborhood.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$A = [0,2\pi)$ and $C = S^1$ are not homeomorphic because:
1. $A$ is not compact, $C$ is compact.
2. $A$ has many cut points, $C$ has none.
3. $A$ is contractable, $C$ is not.
4. $A$ is simply connected, $C$ is not.

As you were showing if $f:A \to C$ is homeomorphism,
then $f^{-1}$ is not continuous.  It cannot be continuous
since continuous images of compact spaces are compact and
since $C$ is compact, $A$ would have to be compact which it isn't.

Comment: I understand your answer and it is nice. But would you explain the answer given in Wikipedia as follows:  " The function $f^{-1}$ is not continuous at the point $( 1 , 0 )$ because although $ f^{-1}$ maps $( 1 , 0 )$ to $0$,  any neighbourhood of this point also includes points that the function maps close to $2 \pi $, but the points it maps to numbers in between lie outside the neighborhood. "                                                   I could not understand this explanation. Would you explain it?

Comment: @M.A.SARKAR.  Because the preimage of a small opened ended arc about (1,0) would have the form [0,a)  $\cup$ (b,2$\pi$).

Comment: what are $a,b$ ?  I think $a,b \in [0, 2 \pi)$. Is not it? But how to chose $a,b$ then?